# How to find and group by a field that is inside a sub-collection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Collection:

```
[{
    _id: "Jon"
    gender: "male",
    sockets: [
        { code: 12345, type: 'default' },
        { code: 67891, type: 'special' }
    ]
},
{
    _id: "Jane"
    gender: "female",
    sockets: [
        { code: 445566, type: 'very_special' },
        { code: 223388, type: 'extra_special' }
    ]
}]
```

I want to run a search for the code field. So the user starts typing a code and should be suggested with found codes. E.g. when typing **1** results should be

```
[{ 
    _id: "Jon", code: 12345
}, {
    _id: "Jon", code: 67891
}]
```

I know I have to use aggregation with grouping. But I cannot find any example how to do this for my use case. If I would group by a standard field I would use this. But this does not apply to a sub-collection like sockets:

```
collection.aggregate([{
    $group: {
       _id: "$code"
    }
}]);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you deal with "arrays" in the aggregation framework you generally want to [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) first. This effectively  "de-normalizes" your document into separate documents for each array entry.

The other thing here for the type of "grouping" you possibly want is that `_id` can contain a combination of fields to "group" on rather than just a single field value. Possibly no difference from just processing `$unwind` here in this example, but for an application of [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) you do it like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$sockets" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": { "_id": "$_id", "code": "$sockets.code" }
    }}
])
```

Generally you actually really want to "group" on something, but perhaps you just want the "de-normalized" form, which you can also do with [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$sockets" },
    { "$project": {
        "_id": 1,
        "code": "$sockets.code"
    }}
])
```